# Spark Streaming - Java - Insert JSON from Kafka into Cassandra

Tags: java, json, cassandra, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm writing a simple data pipeline in Spark Streaming, using Java, to pull JSON data from Kafka, parse the JSON into a custom class (`Transaction`), then insert that data into a Cassandra table but I am unable to get the `mapToRow()` function to work.

I've seen tons of examples that say all you have to do is something along the lines of this:

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
        streamingContext,
        String.class, 
        String.class, 
        StringDecoder.class, 
        StringDecoder.class,
        kafkaParams,
        topicsSet
);

JavaDStream<String> lines = stream.map(
    new Function<Tuple2<String,String>, String>(){
        @Override
        public String call(Tuple2<String,String> tuple2) {
            return tuple2._2();
        }
    }
);

javaFunctions(lines).writerBuilder("myKeyspace", "myTableName", mapToRow(Transaction.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

However, when I do this I get the error:

```
The method mapToRow(Class<Transaction>) is undefined for the type SaveTransactions
```

I think all I am lacking is some sort of decoration on my class but I have not been successful in figuring out which one.  I've tried going bare bones, essentially making the class a property bag:

```
public class Transaction implements java.io.Serializable{

    public int TransactionId;
    ...

    public Transaction(){}
}
```

I've tried all of the DataStax mapping annotations:

```
@Table(keyspace = "myKeyspace", name = "myTableName",
       readConsistency = "QUORUM",
       writeConsistency = "QUORUM",
       caseSensitiveKeyspace = false,
       caseSensitiveTable = false)
public class Transaction implements java.io.Serializable{

    @PartitionKey(0)
    @Column(name="transaction_id")
    public int TransactionId;
    ...

    public Transaction(){}
}
```

I also tried establishing public get/set methods for each property and setting the properties to private:

```
public class Transaction implements java.io.Serializable{

    private int transactionId;
    ...

    public Transaction(){}

    public int getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;
    }

    public void setTransactionId(int transactionId) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }
}
```

I have been able to parse the `DStream` into an `RDD` of `Transactions` using the class below:

```
public class Transaction implements java.io.Serializable{

    ...

    public static class ParseJSON implements FlatMapFunction<Iterator<String>, Transaction> {
        public Iterable<Transaction> call(Iterator<String> lines) throws Exception {
            ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                while (lines.hasNext()) {
                    String line = lines.next();
                    try {
                        transactions.add(mapper.readValue(line, Transaction.class));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Skipped:" + e);
                    }
                }

                return transactions;
        }
    }
}
```

In conjunction with the following code, acting on the `lines` object from above:

```
JavaDStream<Transaction> events = lines.mapPartitions(new Transaction.ParseJSON());
```

However, once I have it in this from it still doesn't work with the writeBuilder().saveToCassandra() chain.

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was just an import issue.  I had imported `com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.*` thinking it would give me everything I needed however I also needed to bring in `com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.*` for the .mapToRow() function.

Once I resolved this, I began getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/package$ScalaReflectionLock$
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ReflectionLock$.<init>(ReflectionLock.scala:5)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ReflectionLock$.<clinit>(ReflectionLock.scala)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.ReflectionColumnMapper.<init>(ReflectionColumnMapper.scala:38)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.JavaBeanColumnMapper.<init>(JavaBeanColumnMapper.scala:10)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.JavaApiHelper$.javaBeanColumnMapper(JavaApiHelper.scala:93)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.JavaApiHelper.javaBeanColumnMapper(JavaApiHelper.scala)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(CassandraJavaUtil.java:1204)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(CassandraJavaUtil.java:1222)
    at globalTransactions.Process.main(Process.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.package$ScalaReflectionLock$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

Which was resolved by pulling in the spark-sql project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps the next guy/gal.